# Displaying signature capture image

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

I have an app that asks the user for information then their signature. Upon clicking the "sign" button they are taken to a view controller called "myviewcontroller".

From there what I want to show is the following screen, however whenever I click the "sign" button the signature capture takes the entire screen, and while it works I am unable to see the "x" where they should sign.

I don't know what I am missing, or what I've incorrectly called that's causing this to happen.

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize mySignatureImage;
@synthesize lastContactPoint1, lastContactPoint2, currentPoint;
@synthesize imageFrame;
@synthesize fingerMoved;
@synthesize navbarHeight;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set the title of the navigation view
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Sign here"];

    //create a save button in the navigation bar
    UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(saveSignature:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myButton];
    //set the view background to light gray
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    //get reference to the navigation frame to calculate navigation bar height
    CGRect navigationframe = [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame];
    navbarHeight = navigationframe.size.height;

    //create a frame for our signature capture based on whats remaining
    imageFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+10,
                            self.view.frame.origin.y-5,
                            self.view.frame.size.width-20,
                            self.view.frame.size.height-navbarHeight-30);

    //allocate an image view and add to the main view
    mySignatureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    mySignatureImage.frame = imageFrame;
    mySignatureImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:mySignatureImage];


}
```

There's more code for the actual signature capture, but this is the stuff directly related to the view controller.

http://i59.tinypic.com/f06ph2.jpg
http://i61.tinypic.com/29cqy8.jpg

Comment: can u give more clarity on 'X'

Comment: Sure, it's just a png image in the background that has the x and line where the user should sign. http://i61.tinypic.com/29cqy8.jpg shows what that looks like

Comment: where u added that image...

Comment: added it to the xcode project, and then added an imageview in the view controller. Set the image as the png